# startOfDay date converted when printed

Tags: swift, xcode, timezone

I'm in a GMT+1 timezone.

Function `startOfDay` should return "the first moment of the given date".
In my case for date *"2020-11-10 19:52:52 +0000\n"* I should get *"2020-11-10 00:00:00 +0000\n"*, but I'm getting *"2020-11-09 23:00:00 +0000\n"* (desired time - 1 hour).

As you can see in the screenshot, variable is set up correctly, but when I try to print it, it is magically converted. It looks like swift is converting it on the fly, but why?

At first, I thought that maybe somehow I have different timezone for Calendar object, but when I print `Calendar.current.timeZone.abbreviation()` the result is "GMT+1", same as for Date object or `TimeZone.current.abbreviation()`.

[Xcode playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTB9u.jpg)

Comment: Dates have no concept of time zone, and `print` calls in to `Date.description`, which has no concept of what time zone you might want. Dates are therefore always printed in UTC unless you format them using `DateFormatter` first using the correct time zone, and printing the produced strings.

Comment: +0000 means zeroSecondsFromGMT

Comment: if you would like to print your local time without using dateFormatter you can print your date description with Locale `date.description(with: .current)`